# Reading multi column sheet from excel file and appending them vertically

Tags: r

I have list of sheets from an excel file where the I want to extract 3 columns from each of them and append them. For one sheet the way it is done is this:

```
gather_sheet<- function(file_path, sheet_name, section_names) {
  data <- readxl::read_excel(file_path, sheet = sheet_name)
  
  col_names <- colnames(data)
  
  start_cols <- numeric(length(section_names))
  
  for (i in seq_along(section_names)) {
    start_col <- grep(section_names[i], col_names, ignore.case = TRUE)
    if (length(start_col) == 0) {
      warning(paste("Section", section_names[i], "not found in the file. Skipping..."))
    } else {
      start_cols[i] <- start_col
    }
  }
  
  start_cols <- start_cols[start_cols != 0]
  
  section_data <- lapply(start_cols, function(start_col) {
    data[, c(start_col, start_col + 1, start_col + 3)]  # Selecting Gene, logFC, and P_Value columns
  })
  
  # Set column names for each section
  for (i in seq_along(section_data)) {
    colnames(section_data[[i]]) <- c("Gene", "logFC", "P_Value")
  }
  
  combined_df <- do.call(rbind, section_data)
  
  return(combined_df)
}

file_path <- "Cancer/Gene_curated_PMC/PMC7026087/test_MDD.xlsx"
sheet_name <- "S4"
section_names <- c("Genetic sex differences in BLA under nonstress conditions",
                   "Genetic sex differences in PFC under nonstress conditions",
                   "Genetic sex differences in NAc under nonstress conditions")

result_df <- gather_sheet(file_path, sheet_name, section_names)

head(result_df)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Gene    logFC                P_Value               
  <chr>   <chr>                <chr>                 
1 NA      NA                   NA                    
2 Gene    logFC                P_Value               
3 Xist    -8.0373292919600594  4.9790407500619702E-15
4 Eif2s3x -0.62587559933772996 1.67736565429711E-11  
5 Tmsb4x  0.79205829258763805  3.6028831287886302E-10
6 Msl3    0.91171187697942302  3.6974211142700799E-10
```

Here the issue is for each sheet I have to give `section_names`. Is there a way where I can read this on the go from the excel sheet itself, instead getting it as argument. I will give small set of the data from another sheet

```
structure(list(`Pure sex differences in BLA under nonstress conditions` = c(NA, 
"Gene", "Xist", "Eif2s3x", "Frmpd4", "Arhgap6"), ...2 = c(NA, 
"logFC", "-8.3404673224955399", "-0.59460603380030097", "0.72227752389018696", 
"1.0307297751939699"), ...3 = c(NA, "t", "-45.522550127632599", 
"-13.045033349452201", "10.9440201431088", "10.9233494765526"
), ...4 = c(NA, "P_Value", "8.1679531862325995E-11", "1.3151229751782599E-6", 
"4.9057934659385896E-6", "4.9751964230428604E-6"), ...5 = c(NA, 
"B", "4.7913233921023801", "6.12938466938839", "4.8322080710430404", 
"4.8049143096335101"), ...6 = c(NA, "FC_PureSex", "-324.13866710994103", 
"-1.5100601672178", "1.6497844273173099", "2.0430574535622998"
), ...7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `Pure sex differences in PFC under nonstress conditions` = c(NA, 
"Gene", "Xist", "Tmsb4x", "Msl3", "Eif2s3x"), ...10 = c(NA, "logFC", 
"-8.9254737965647006", "0.66691082196642604", "0.91857291442757705", 
"-0.55314789195542702"), ...11 = c(NA, "t", "-17.748403897464598", 
"12.5716346851104", "10.8214316283416", "-9.7973768434406097"
), ...12 = c(NA, "P_Value", "8.5277624397678303E-9", "2.2174736548458499E-7", 
"8.84128504278794E-7", "2.1780415478059698E-6"), ...13 = c(NA, 
"B", "3.65746318391342", "7.7021480698451699", "6.2871882191315098", 
"5.4436659960516396"), ...14 = c(NA, "FC_PureSex", "-486.222820511691", 
"1.5876697194038401", "1.89024457559132", "-1.4672837490239501"
), ...15 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...16 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `Pure sex differences in NAc under nonstress conditions` = c(NA, 
"Gene", "Xist", "Nms", "Prps2", "Shbg"), ...18 = c(NA, "logFC", 
"-8.0077667977712608", "-1.8194723603816101", "0.81288835925618996", 
"-3.1738596176035698"), ...19 = c(NA, "t", "-9.6354991133483097", 
"-7.4211279525496501", "7.1829765648280297", "-7.0912929527637001"
), ...20 = c(NA, "P_Value", "3.05944341486859E-5", "1.6005233151291301E-4", 
"1.95787536285021E-4", "2.11882827817144E-4"), ...21 = c(NA, 
"B", "-4.2498922130894297", "-4.3358435409807701", "-3.3803539700154301", 
"-4.5243130863905803"), ...22 = c(NA, "FC_PureSex", "-257.38190111638102", 
"-3.5295208906495001", "1.75672498974684", "-9.0245789142984592"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
```

So my final objective is for each sheet I want them to be this 3 column data frame, it would be helpful if the sheet name can be added as one column so that its easily identified

```
Gene    logFC                P_Value               
  <chr>   <chr>                <chr>                 
1 NA      NA                   NA                    
2 Gene    logFC                P_Value               
3 Xist    -8.0373292919600594  4.9790407500619702E-15
4 Eif2s3x -0.62587559933772996 1.67736565429711E-11  which i want to use downstream
```

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated